# Direct Summation of the same space , meaning?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

In a course , there is the definition of the notation :(for V a G module over a finite group)
$$V^{\oplus n}=V\oplus V\oplus ...\oplus V\quad(\text{n times})$$
But i don't understand the sense of this object , for $x\in V^{\oplus n}$ there is no unicity for the writing x=$v_1+v_2+...+v_n$ so what's the meaning of the direct sum , i don't get it,

Comment: just imagine you throw a formal variable into all the copies. In  the end what you look at is more or less the n fold cartesian product. So just think of it as n-tuples of objects in $V$. The direct sum actually does not care if it is the same space as it is defined via a universal property!

Comment: I'm not convinced yet , maybe there is something i did not understood in the definition of the direct summation but i can't pass through the problem of the unicity of the writing . I don't find sense to change every copy by a formal variable , isn't it important that they are the same sets ?

Comment: Ah, I presume you think of the "internal" direct sum. this is just the plain direct sum. I really like this definition, but it might be a little advanced:
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+sum
However. generally you always have a direct sum (most of the time the cartesian product). when you write $U\oplus W$ for subspaces, you actually write $U+W$ and $U\cap V=0$ it is just a shorthand. And I think that is what you are struggling with. you are considering $V$ here not as a subspace of itself, but a completely different space.

Comment: Yes you perfectly understood , i wasn't thinking about the exterior direct sum , but about the internal one. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the exterior direct sum. As a vector space, it is the Cartesian product $V^n$ equipped with componentwise addition. Though there is a slight difference where infinite direct sums are concerned. In general,
$$\bigoplus_{i\in I} V_i=\{(v_i)_{i\in I}~\vert~v_i=0\textrm{ for all but finitely many }i\in I\}$$
equipped with componentwise addition and $\lambda(v_i)_{i\in I}=(\lambda v_i)_{i\in I}$ as multiplication.

But the *idea* is that the exterior direct sum is a vector space into which you can embed all the summands such that the space is the interior direct sum (the one you're familiar with) of the embedded spaces. In this way, we have, for instance $\mathbb R^2\cong \mathbb R\oplus\mathbb R$, since we can embed the first instance of $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R^2$ like this: $r\mapsto(r,0)$, and the second instance like this: $r\mapsto(0,r)$. The corresponding images are subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$, and $\mathbb R^2$ is the (interior) direct sum of those subspaces. And then we say that it is the exterior direct sum of two instances of $\mathbb R$ . Basically, we identify the exterior direct summands with fitting interior direct summands of their exterior direct sum.